# What does the "nearby" trait do in the manager job conditions?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

The new manager interface allows you to set conditions on repeating jobs.

What qualifies an item with the "nearby" trait in the conditions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be in a stockpile, or 20 tiles of the initial position. `20 tiles from the workshop for example`.

I think you should be able to access it too, if it have no way to access the stockpile or workshop it will not be available as nearby.

*Edit: I was trying to find a source, and remember to see it in the wiki http://dwarffortresswiki.org but the best thing I found is:*

- *http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Butcher#Troubleshooting*

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is that 20 tiles horizontally, regardless of z-level? Either way, that use of "Nearby" sounds consistent with general workshop behavior. Thank you.

Comment: If I have several workshops, does it choose one or count them all? but anyway thanks, I will test it in new fortress.